# TFS 2013 Add and reffer to new link type

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-2013

I would like to add proper management for Duplicated bugs.
My plans were to Add new link type "Duplicating" and to prevent move to "Duplicated" in case the new linktype ==0.

Steps Taken:
Add new link type: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd273716.aspx
preventing:

```
<FIELD refname="My.DuplicatingBug">
    <WHEN field="My.LinkType.Duplicating" value="0">
      <COPY from="value" value="0" />
    </WHEN>
    <COPY from="value" value="Valid Completed Work time" />
    <PROHIBITEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="0" />
    </PROHIBITEDVALUES>         
</FIELD>
```

Yet, when trying to import the new WIT, The following prompts:

> Error importing work item type definition:
> TF201000: Field reference name My.LinkType.Duplicating conflicts with an existing link type. The name is already in use.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that on your bug work item definition you have defined 2 fields: My.DuplicatingBug and My.LinkType.Duplicating

When you created your custom link you probably defined it as

When you're uploading the new bug definition, the field reference is clashing with the link type reference.

I'm not 100% certain but I don't think there is a way to add a conditional value to a field based on a link type.

Could you perhaps add a new field on the Bug work item called "Duplicate Bug ID" and even a new closed state of "Duplicate" and you can only move into the Duplicate state if you have populated the "Duplicate Bug ID"